# breakout collision detection using vectors

Tags: c++

I am working on a breakout game using C++ and OpenGL. I have stubbed out some code using straight C++. I am  using a vector to store objects.

I want to streamline my collision detection code.I am working on breakout game using vectors to store brick values in text based c++ to start with. Well I am attempting to use a vector as a dynamic array. Basically I want to store the values of the bricks in a vector. I then want to iterate through the vector in order to determine if a brick is hit by the ball. I am able to detect if a single brick is hit by the ball but I want to determine if a vector of brick values are hit by a ball. In other words instead of using a collision detection loop for each and every single brick one at a time but I want the vector to store the values for the bricks so that I can iterate through them dynamically.

My code:

```cpp
class Brick
{
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float brick_x;
    float brick_y;
    float brickWidth;
    float brickHeight;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Brick> brick;
    Brick playerBrick;
    Brick playerBrick_two;

    playerBrick.x = 30.0f;
    playerBrick.y = 20.0f;
    playerBrick.brick_x = 20.0f;
    playerBrick.brick_y = 10.0f;
    playerBrick.brickWidth = 60.0f;
    playerBrick.brickHeight = 20.0f;

    playerBrick_two.x = 40.0f;
    playerBrick_two.y = 30.0f;
    playerBrick_two.brick_x = 30.0f;
    playerBrick_two.brick_y = 20.0f;
    playerBrick_two.brickWidth = 60.0f;
    playerBrick_two.brickHeight = 20.0f;

    brick.push_back(playerBrick);
    brick.push_back(playerBrick_two);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << brick[i].x << " " << brick[i].y << " " << brick[i].brick_x << " " << brick[i].brick_y << " " << brick[i].brickWidth << " " << brick[i].brickHeight << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (brick[i].x > brick[i].brick_x && brick[i].x < brick[i].brick_x + brick[i].brickWidth && brick[i].y > brick[i].brick_y && brick[i].y < brick[i].brick_y + brick[i].brickHeight)
        {
            cout << "Collision" << endl;
        }
    }

void bricks_eight()
{
    glColor3f(0.8f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRectf(50.0f, 60.0f, 70.0f, 50.0f);
    glRectf(70.0f, 60.0f, 90.0f, 50.0f);
    glRectf(90.0f, 60.0f, 110.0f, 50.0f);
    glRectf(110.0f, 60.0f, 130.0f, 50.0f);
    glRectf(130.0f, 60.0f, 150.0f, 50.0f);
    glRectf(150.0f, 60.0f, 170.0f, 50.0f);
}
```

Well I am posting a row of bricks I want to eliminate when the ball strikes with them. Since I have several rows of bricks I want to use a collision detection function that checks for a ball and brick collision using a vector. The x and y variables are the ball coordinates and the brick_x and brick_y variables and the brick coordinates.

I adjusted Makogan's code but it still does not check for a lot  collisions all at once.

```
``
class Brick
{
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float brick_x=0.0f;
    float brick_y=0.0f;
    float brickWidth=20.0f;
    float brickHeight=10.0f;
    bool TestCollision(float x, float y)
    {
        if (x > brick_x && x<brick_x + brickWidth && y > brick_y && y < brick_y + brickHeight)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

class BrickLayer
{
public:
    vector<Brick> bricks{(5.0f,5.0f)};
    bool TestCollisions(float x, float y) {
        for (auto& brick : bricks) if (brick.TestCollision(x, y)) return true;
        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    BrickLayer brick;
    cout << brick.TestCollisions(5.0f,5.0f)<< endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to be far more specific as to what the desired output and current output is and if you can, provide a minimum working example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I am still not 100% of what you are trying to achieve. Reading your question it sounds like you could just loop through the array, detect collisions with every brick and store the results in another vector.

Comment: I am trying to detect collisions for all the bricks at the same time not just one collision function for each and every brick. The reason I am using  a vector is because I can dynamically test for every collision without all the overhead of an array.

Comment: An array and a vector are essentially the same thing, the only difference is that the size of a vector is dynamic, so I am not sure what you mean by overhead they have the exact same behaviour.

"I am trying to detect collisions for all the bricks at the same time not just one collision function for each and every brick"

The set of all collisions is the same as the union of singleton sets containing one of the collisions in the set.

Computationally, you can't avoid having to test collisions sequentially. I am assuming that your issue is that your loop is slow, is that correct?

Comment: I have a lot of bricks to test for so I need an collision detection function that is simple and easy to use.

Comment: The easiest collision detection is just a for loop. In order to avoid rewriting the check you can add is as a member to your brick class. i.e Add a member function `testCollision(x,y)` and then you just loop over every individual brick and  test each individual collision.

That's slow but simple. 

If what you want is simply to test detection with a whole row, if you can make the assumption that the row is a rectangle, then you can simply have a wrapper class around the vector that stores the dimensions of the rectangle made by the bricks in that row.

Comment: If you want to test against arbitrary shapes, which is a possibility in a breakout game, then you no longer have a `simple and easy` solution because the problem is more complex.

Comment: Just like you have a brick class which represents a single brick, have a BirckLayer class that represents a row of bricks. And store the maximum and minimum boundaries of the entire row

Comment: do you think I should check for a whole row or just one brick at a time, which would be better at solving my problem?

Comment: "Better" is completely dependent on your use case, doing the loop is the easiest to code, so it;s a good place to start. However, that can become slow, if you see your program lag, then you may need to implement more clever algorithms to avoid doing useless computations.

Comment: what is a instance? sorry but there are so many terms in computer science.

Comment: a class is a generic description of an object. An instance is a particular case of that object. so in your case, `Brick` is a class. But `playerBrick` and `playerBrick_two` are both instances of the class.

Also [lease post the questions about my answer under the answer

Comment: `BrickLayer brick;
    cout << brick.TestCollisions(5.0f,5.0f)<< endl;`

You are not initializing any values there, the brick array is empty. Look, it is clear you don't have much experience with programming. I want to advise you to look at the code you posted and think why it makes sense that it isn;t working (the way you wrote it) and how to fix it.

Hint: data needs to be initialized.

Comment: cool I will work on it I am little confused on how the  for loop works.

Comment: That for loop iterates over every element of the array, if the array is empty, then it never runs as there are no elements to iterate over.

If that syntax confuses you, replace with classic `for(int i=0; i<array.size() < i++)`

Comment: cool I  understand the above loop, it iterates over a loop of size of the array

Comment: is there any tutorials that can help me?

Comment: Well, you can try basic C++ tutorials

Comment: any in particular that  you would recommend?

Comment: I had 3 years of programming experience before learning C++ so I am not sure any of the ones I used would be helpful. If you can, read the learnprogramming subreddit for suggestions.

Comment: I edited my code and  have initialized the bricks vector

Comment: Post it in your question, not as an edit to my answer

Comment: I thought I did post to my question

Comment: You are not initializing the array. I recommend, look online for `default constructor c++` And initialize ALL fields in the array. 

This should not be working: `vector<Brick> bricks{(5.0f,5.0f)};`

Comment: actually it does work but I will lookup default constructors as well

Comment: I doesn't, most of your fields are left uninitialized

Comment: I reposted my code

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, it sounds like you just need a wrapper to abstract detecting collisions for a group / row of your bricks.

So my suggestion is

```
class Brick
{
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float brick_x;
    float brick_y;
    float brickWidth;
    float brickHeight;
    TestCollision(float x,float y) {/* check goes here */}
};

class BrickLayer
{
public:
    vector<Brick> bricks;
    float min_x;
    float min_y;
    float total_width;
    float total_height;

    BrickLayer(vector<Brick> bricks) {/* initialize the instance fields here */}
    // Option 1, iterating over every brick:
    bool TestCollisions(float x, float y) {
        for(auto& brick : bricks) if(brick.testCollision(x,y)) return true;
         return false;
    }
    // Option 2, use cached information:
    bool TestCollisions(float x, float y) {
       if (x > min_x && x < min_x + total_width && y > min_y && y < min_y + total_height)
        return true;
    }

};
```

Comment: @gamer67

Of course only the the single `TestCollission` check does not test for collisions with multiple bricks. It only tests for collisions with one. Let me be more specific with my answer, see if that helps.

Comment: well my problem is that I have a lot of bricks to check for collision and I want to  use an algorithm that checks for collisions more efficiently.

Comment: I am trying to nail down this problem let me know very specifically what I can help you with.

Comment: Well, the second version of the algorithm that I gave you will take longer to initialize, but collision testing will be more efficient.

Comment: The main question is if it works for you. If it does, please accept the answer, and ideally give an upvote.

Comment: Almost? Can you please expand?

Comment: well no  matter what I put in the TestCollisions bool and for loop it does not return true.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using the functions with  a for loop

Comment: Can you edit your question with the current implementation you are using, as well as the shell output of the paremeters and output?